# How to call php download function in command line?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, download, downloading-website-files

I have a data set that is downloadable via a website link. I would like to call that from the command line rather than from a browser.

That broswer link appears to call a PHP script. Is there a way to run this file and pull the resulting data set to a remote server via command line rather than pull to my desktop via a browser?

This is an example of the url:

http://...datasets/content_loader.php

Answer (score 0):

**use command :** wget [your link]